# How to serializer/deserialize Django models

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

My current Django REST Framework application has a Parameter model with 2 fields: "key" and "value". Currently, my REST API asks clients for a list of dictionaries with always the same keys: "key" and "value:

```
[
    {
        "key": "my_param_name_1",
        "value": "my_param_value_1"
    },
    {
        "key": "my_param_name_2",
        "value": "my_param_value_2"
    }
]
```

I'm aware that this request format could be improved: a single dictionary with "key" fields as keys and "value" fields as values would make client requests simpler and more concise. Here is an example of what I want:

```
{
    "my_param_name_1": "my_param_value_1",
    "my_param_name_2": "my_param_value_2"
}
```

I currently have a ParameterSerializer class which inherits from serializers.Serializer. Here is the code:

```
class ParameterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    key = serializers.CharField()    # This forces me to have "key" in every parameter dictionary...
    value = serializers.CharField()  # Same comment for "value".

    class Meta:
        models = Parameter
```

It looks like rest_framework's serializers only accept predetermined dictionary keys ("key" and "value") and not variable dictionary keys, which is what the new proposed format uses. So far, I have found no way to make built-in serializers work with the new format.

Any clue on what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally removed this serializer because what I really needed to do was to modify the serializer that made use of this use as a class member:

```
class ConfigurationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parameters = ParameterSerializer(many=True, source='parameter_set')
```

Before going further, the Configuration model contains a set of Parameter models.

So, in ConfigurationSerializer, I replaced ParameterSerializer with a field class variable that inherits from serializers.WritableField:

```
class ConfigurationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parameters = ParametersField(source="parameter_set")

    class Meta:
        model = Configuration
        fields = ('id', 'version', 'resource', 'option', 'name', 'parameters')
```

Here is how ParametersField looks like:

```
class ParametersField(serializers.WritableField):
    def from_native(self, parameters_dict):
        """
        Transform a dictionary of parameters to Django model objects.

        :param parameters_dict: A dictionary of parameters keyed by name.
        :type  parameters_dict: dict

        :returns: A list of Parameter model instances.
        :rtype: list
        """

        print(str([Parameter(key=name, value=value)
                  for name, value in parameters_dict.iteritems()]))
        return [Parameter(key=name, value=value)
                for name, value in parameters_dict.iteritems()]

    def to_native(self, parameter_set):
        """
        Transform the parameters to a dictionary.

        :param parameters: A list of Parameter model instances.
        :type  parameters: list

        :returns: A dictionary of parameters keyed by name.
        :rtype: dict
        """

        parameters_dict = {}
        for parameter in parameter_set.all():
            parameters_dict[parameter.key] = parameter.value
        return parameters_dict
```

The WritableField class allows the serialization of any model to an arbitrary Python data structure. Because I return JSON to clients, I chose to transform the set of Parameters models of the Configuration model to a dictionary.

Hope this helps!